# Parquet support for 'tinyint' columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I am running into this strange issue when using AWS Athena to query parquet data on S3.
 Basically, I have one parquet file (about 38MB) stored on S3 with the following schema:

Table name: test_table_tinyint

- ntwk_id (int)
- broadcast_date (string)
- daypart_id (tinyint)

Then I run the following query:
SELECT count(*) FROM "test_table_tinyint" where daypart_id = 5;

The result:
Run time: 2.7 seconds, Data scanned: 32MB

This is strange because it looks like instead of utilizing the column index in the parquet file, it actually conducted a full table scan.

Then as a comparison, I created another table with the same data but slightly different schema:

Table name: test_table_int

- ntwk_id (int)
- broadcast_date (string)
- daypart_id (int)

SELECT count(*) FROM "test_table_int" where daypart_id = 5;

This time I got a much better result:

Run time: 1.07 seconds, Data scanned: 326.49KB

I ran into the similar issue in Spark with Spark SQL, Looks like TinyInt columns in parquet files would cause the full table scan. If I convert the file to ORC format, then both AWS Athena and Spark SQL got similar result with 'TinyInt' as with 'Int'

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: This is most likely related to a coercion,  `daypart_id = 5` is actually `CAST(daypart_id AS INTEGER) = 5`. You can try to work around this with giving the constant an explicit type: `daypart_id = TINYINT '5'`.

Comment: Thanks, @PiotrFindeisen using explicit type works.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is because when `daypart_id` is a TINYINT, `daypart_id = 5` is actually `CAST(daypart_id AS INTEGER) = 5` (coercion is from narrower to wider type).

To prevent coercion from happening and messing with push down you can give the `5` constant and explicit type: `daypart_id = TINYINT '5'`.

Note: I am almost certain newer versions of Presto has this problem fixed, so you wouldn't need to change your query. You can use newer Presto versions on AWS quite easily, just not serverless.